# Hide div if value inside is set to 0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have code like below:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 StockNumber">
    In Stock: 
    <span class="NumberOfStock">
        <?php echo $this->product->product_in_stock ?>
    </span>
</div>
```

Here is example how it works: http://www.avanti-studio.pl/index.php/kolekcje/kardigany/sweter-pudrowy-5-detail ("W magazynie: 0").

What I want to do is to hide all "StockNumber" div if value in "NumberOfStock" span is "0". How it can be done?

Thx for any help.

Comment: value inside div or span

Comment: `<?php if($this->product->product_in_stock == 0){?>
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 StockNumber" style = "visibility:hidden;">In Stock: <span class="NumberOfStock"><?php echo $this->product->product_in_stock ?></span></div>
<?php } ?>`

Comment: Hi Anant, I tried your code, but it hide div even if there is number bigger than 0...

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code it will work

```
$(".StockNumber span:contains('0')").parent('div').hide();
```

Comment: Hi uzaif, thank you for help, I put your code in custom.js in my template: http://www.avanti-studio.pl/templates/horme_3/js/custom.js but as you can see div is still visible...: http://www.avanti-studio.pl/index.php/kolekcje/kardigany/sweter-pudrowy-5-detail

Comment: any console error why you pass $ in callback function

Comment: There is a javascript error: remove $ from function($),  Close the statement with ); in the last line

Comment: your custom.js does not contain ) in end

Comment: Oh, sorry... I fell shame. Now it works great. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

This only outputs the div if there is stock.

```
<?php if($this->product->product_in_stock>0){ ?>
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 StockNumber">
    In Stock: 
    <span class="NumberOfStock">
        <?php echo $this->product->product_in_stock ?>
    </span>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```